# Getting value of element with javascript from jsp page

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have the following jsp form:

```
<form action = "dt.jsp" METHOD = "GET" ONSUBMIT="return validateForm()">
   <table>
      <tr>
        <td><input type=date name="fdate"/></td>
        <td><input type=date name="tdate"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input  TYPE = "SUBMIT" VALUE = "Search by date">
</form>
```

and javascript function:

```
function validateForm()
{
    alert(document.getElementsByName('fdate').value);
    return false;
}
```

when I do the alert I get undefined. why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`document.getElementsByName('fdate')` returns an array, or more accurately a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

Use `document.getElementsByName('fdate')[0].value`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName

Comment: Thank you.
now I try to compare this 2 dates like this:
    function validateForm()
    {
       if(dates.compare(document.getElementsByName('fdate')        [0].value,
                  document.getElementsByName('tdate')[0].value) == -1)
    {
      alert("to date must be bigger then from date");
      return false;
    }
}

what is the problem?

Comment: @user3557163 You have to ask a new question. At StackOverflow, we have one issue per question to keep questions more useful to other users.